# Adding covariates in chi-squared test or proportions test?

Tags: logistic, chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution, proportion, likelihood-ratio

I am having trouble figuring out what analysis is appropriate for my research question. I've been googling for the past few days but couldn't find the answer. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could provide some thoughts or comments.

Below is my research question, which I only changed the names of the variables to make it more straightforward:

Suppose that I hypothesize that people will prefer eating chocolates over candies. So I collected participants and asked them which they like more, chocolate or candy.

Thus in my model, the dependent variable is a categorical variable with two levels (0=candy, 1=chocolate). Then I ran chi-squared goodness of fit analysis and found out that 85% of participants preferred chocolate, and 15% preferred candy -- which supported my hypothesis that people prefer chocolates over candies, and that it's not an even split (50% vs. 50%).

But I found out that age is correlated with the preference for chocolate, such that older people are more likely to choose chocolate over candy.

**Thus I want to control for the effect of age, such that even after accounting for age, significantly more people will still prefer chocolates over candies.****

I’ve been trying to figure out how to do this. I don’t think I can include covariates when running the chi-squared goodness of fit analysis. And binomial logistic regression doesn’t seem to work here either because I don’t have a predictor variable, but just the covariate (i.e., age) and the dependent variable (i.e., chocolate vs. candy). Or would the likelihood-ratio test serve the purpose here?

I would really appreciate it if anyone could provide any suggestions on the analysis.

Thank you very much for your time!

Best,
Jean

Comment: why do you think binomial logistic regression doesn't work here?

Comment: @bdeonovic I thought binomial logistic regression is used when making predictions, thus would need predictors/independent variables. In my case, I don't have an independent variable (though I have a covariate) in the model, so I thought logistic regression would not work here. Do you think that is the appropriate analysis?

Comment: @bdeonovic And when I did run the binomial logistic regression, the results I see are the estimates and significance of the intercept and the age variable, and I wasn't sure that's the info that answers my research question.

Answer (score 1):

You state that the hypothesis you are interested in is that the proportion of people who prefer chocolate is larger than .5. You also state that this proportion is influenced by age, and you want to control for that. However saying that the proportion is influenced by age, means that there is no longer a single proportion, but one proportion for each age. So the problem is your hypothesis no longer makes sense. The solution is to think about what it is that you want to know exactly (e.g. do you want to know the proportion of an average aged person or the average proportion). What the right hypothesis for your problem is depends on the details. Since this is obviously a fictional example, there is not much more to be said here.

Comment: In many ways it is unfortunate that we are still teaching contengency table/$\chi^2$ test methods.  I say that because these are special cases of categorical regression models such as binary, ordinal, and multinomial logistic regression models, and contingency table thinking invites us to not think of accounting for outcome heterogeneity (due to age, etc.).  Once you are familiar w/regression parameters you can get any predicted probabilities of your choosing & easily convert between intercepts+slopes and log odds of outcome probs., then get at easy with converting log odds to probabilities.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I understand that point and have liked the elegance of how regression methods generalize basic statistical methods since I got into statistics. However, wouldn't it be a tad overkill to teach the freshman about the full proportional odds model instead of Wilcoxon, leaving the full model to the upperclassmen and grad students? After all, we teach freshmen calculus students root and ratio tests, not convergence of sequences of partial sums in topological vector spaces.

Comment: I don't think so.  Teaching separate methods depending on whether you do or don't need to adjust for covariates creates dichotomous thinking and leaves less time for understanding the methods.  For example most people don't know under which conditions the Wilcoxon test is optimal, and don't know how to handle excessive ties in the data.  The proportional odds model fixes both of those things.  If you have to learn ordinary linear regression you can learn the rest.

Comment: I think there is great value in teaching students how to read and interpret a contingency table in a descriptive sense. Just the moment (some, too few) students have when they realize that statistical analysis is not a form of magic done by people in white lab coats, but something *they* can do and understand, is well worth it. I agree that the value of teaching various tests on a contingency table is questionable.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts, everyone